# Legend display order using bokeh in python

Tags: python, bokeh

I am plotting multiple series of scatter points and specifying the legend label in each scatter() function. The legend itself, however, is displayed in a random order. How can I display them in alphabetical (or other specified) order?

```
figure()
hold()

colors = ['#e41a1c', '#377eb8', '#4daf4a']

def myscatter(x, y, color, legend):
    scatter(x, y, color=color, legend=legend, fill_alpha=0.5, size=10)

myscatter(x1, y1, colors[0], 'x1')
myscatter(x2, y2, colors[1], 'x2')
myscatter(x3, y3 ,colors[2], 'x3')

show()
```

And here's a link to the image based on above code, where legend is displayed in random order: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqXHj.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Currently (as of 0.5.2) Bokeh does not track legend order. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh/issues/926) to track this behavior, and we hope to have it resolved soon!

Comment: Thanks! That would explain why I couldn't find a solution. Wished I had the right brain power to solve the ticket... I look forward to a smart soul out there figuring it out.

Comment: This still is not fixed ... :(